# Dictionary + Thesaurus items duplicated

Tags: macos, imac, dictionary

How can I remove the duplicated menu items?

They show duplicated in the Dashboard Dictionary widget as well, so I guess they get manifested from some general setting. I am new to Mac, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Try going to the Preferences for Dictionary app and unchecking everything and then restart and check what you want to show.

Comment: @TomGewecke Thank you, that worked. I found references in other languages that I'm interested in too. \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Preferences for Dictionary.app and uncheck everything and restart.  Then go back to the Preferences and check what you want to have showing.

Comment: I can just check and uncheck the items, that works for me all right. No need to restart.